# discord.py - trying to retrieve images from imgur

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, imgur

```
@bot.command()
async def album(ctx):
    r = requests.get(f'https://api.imgur.com/3/album/ADDTHISAFTER?client_id={imgur_key}').json()
    em = discord.Embed(title="Title")
    em.set_image(url=str(r[0]["link"]))
    try:
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
    except:
        await ctx.send(str(r[0]["link"]))
```

That's the code I have so far.

I'm trying to connect to a specific album and retrieve a random picture from within. For now, i can't even get it to connect to the damn album.

Putting the link directly into the browser yields this result from the API:

```
{"data":[{"id":"Vb89pCO","title":null,"description":null,"datetime":1586816920,"type":"image\/png","animated":false,"width":1920,"height":1080,"size":3073384,"views":214,"bandwidth":657704176,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":null,"is_ad":false,"in_most_viral":false,"has_sound":false,"tags":[],"ad_type":0,"ad_url":"","edited":"0","in_gallery":false,"deletehash":"bcSfUCo8qxv1Hvn","name":"image.png","link":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/Vb89pCO.png"},{"id":"JTXOKjK","title":null,"description":null,"datetime":1586816865,"type":"image\/png","animated":false,"width":1920,"height":1080,"size":1763552,"views":224,"bandwidth":395035648,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":null,"is_ad":false,"in_most_viral":false,"has_sound":false,"tags":[],"ad_type":0,"ad_url":"","edited":"0","in_gallery":false,"deletehash":"FtBYQpOrtkkWQHs","name":"image.png","link":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/JTXOKjK.png"},{"id":"392h92v","title":null,"description":null,"datetime":1586816875,"type":"image\/png","animated":false,"width":1920,"height":1080,"size":3857695,"views":214,"bandwidth":825546730,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":null,"is_ad":false,"in_most_viral":false,"has_sound":false,"tags":[],"ad_type":0,"ad_url":"","edited":"0","in_gallery":false,"deletehash":"k1dN3s99ctNjHFJ","name":"image.png","link":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/392h92v.png"},{"id":"gNWBnHy","title":null,"description":null,"datetime":1586816890,"type":"image\/png","animated":false,"width":1920,"height":1080,"size":4825975,"views":167,"bandwidth":805937825,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":null,"is_ad":false,"in_most_viral":false,"has_sound":false,"tags":[],"ad_type":0,"ad_url":"","edited":"0","in_gallery":false,"deletehash":"5pNW6XdSS8ozkvL","name":"image.png","link":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/gNWBnHy.png"},{"id":"ugAZxFQ","title":null,"description":null,"datetime":1586816907,"type":"image\/png","animated":false,"width":1920,"height":1080,"size":3106895,"views":132,"bandwidth":410110140,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":null,"is_ad":false,"in_most_viral":false,"has_sound":false,"tags":[],"ad_type":0,"ad_url":"","edited":"0","in_gallery":false,"deletehash":"hDNCb6PaKximuIR","name":"image.png","link":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/ugAZxFQ.png"}],"success":true,"status":200}
```

of which the important bits I need are all the links as in the example shown below:

```
"link":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/Vb89pCO.png"
```

I'd like to temp store all the image links from the given API in an array and randomly select a link and then output that as am image to discord using something like:

```
em = discord.Embed(title="Image")
em.set_image(url="IMAGEURLHERE")
await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Unfortunately I keep getting KeyError: 0, and can't find what that means online.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: `r[0]["link"]` should be `r["data"][0]["link"]`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Shall let you know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is this step:

```
str(r[0]["link"]))

# To show you what is happening:

d = {"list": "foo"}
d["list"]
>> foo
d[0]
>> KeyError: 0
```

The response is a dictionary, which is why you get the KeyError, as that dict does not have 0 as a key.

Based on this:

```
{"data":[{"id":"Vb89pCO","title":null,"description":null,"datetime":1586816920,"type":"image\/png","animated":false,"width":1920,"height":1080,"size":3073384,"views":214,"bandwidth":657704176,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":null,"is_ad":false,"in_most_viral":false,"has_sound":false,"tags":[],"ad_type":0,"ad_url":"","edited":"0","in_gallery":false,"deletehash":"bcSfUCo8qxv1Hvn","name":"image.png","link":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/Vb89pCO.png"},{"id":"JTXOKjK","title":null,"description":null,"datetime":1586816865,"type":"image\/png","animated":false,"width":1920,"height":1080,"size":1763552,"views":224,"bandwidth":395035648,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":null,"is_ad":false,"in_most_viral":false,"has_sound":false,"tags":[],"ad_type":0,"ad_url":"","edited":"0","in_gallery":false,"deletehash":"FtBYQpOrtkkWQHs","name":"image.png","link":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/JTXOKjK.png"},{"id":"392h92v","title":null,"description":null,"datetime":1586816875,"type":"image\/png","animated":false,"width":1920,"height":1080,"size":3857695,"views":214,"bandwidth":825546730,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":null,"is_ad":false,"in_most_viral":false,"has_sound":false,"tags":[],"ad_type":0,"ad_url":"","edited":"0","in_gallery":false,"deletehash":"k1dN3s99ctNjHFJ","name":"image.png","link":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/392h92v.png"},{"id":"gNWBnHy","title":null,"description":null,"datetime":1586816890,"type":"image\/png","animated":false,"width":1920,"height":1080,"size":4825975,"views":167,"bandwidth":805937825,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":null,"is_ad":false,"in_most_viral":false,"has_sound":false,"tags":[],"ad_type":0,"ad_url":"","edited":"0","in_gallery":false,"deletehash":"5pNW6XdSS8ozkvL","name":"image.png","link":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/gNWBnHy.png"},{"id":"ugAZxFQ","title":null,"description":null,"datetime":1586816907,"type":"image\/png","animated":false,"width":1920,"height":1080,"size":3106895,"views":132,"bandwidth":410110140,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":null,"is_ad":false,"in_most_viral":false,"has_sound":false,"tags":[],"ad_type":0,"ad_url":"","edited":"0","in_gallery":false,"deletehash":"hDNCb6PaKximuIR","name":"image.png","link":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/ugAZxFQ.png"}],"success":true,"status":200}
```

You need to change your code to be:

```
r["data"][0]["link"]
# Or perhaps more accurately

for row in r["data"]:
    do_something_with(row["link"])
```

Comment: Thank you for the super quick response! I shall go try and let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of your help! All done and dusted now. Solution is below in case anyone else gets stuck and happens to come across this post.

```
@bot.command()
async def album(ctx):
    r = requests.get(f"https://api.imgur.com/3/album/{album_id}/images?client_id={imgur_key}").json()
    em = discord.Embed(title="Album")
    indexmax = len(r['data']) - 1
    size = random.randrange(0, indexmax, 1)
    em.set_image(url=str(r['data'][size]['link']))
    try:
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
    except:
        await ctx.send(str(r['data'][size]['link']))
```

There's probably a better way to do this but works just fine for me :)

Thanks again for all the help!